# Minikube doesn't run on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, minikube

I had setup VitualBox 6.0.6 on Ubuntu 18.04 and minikube version 1.0.1, and when i run next command

```
minikube start
```

**i got next errors log**

> minikube v1.0.1 on linux (amd64)   Downloading Kubernetes
>   v1.14.1 images in the background ...   Creating virtualbox VM
>   (CPUs=2, Memory=2048MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
>
> Unable to start VM: create: creating: Unable to start the VM:
>   /usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm minikube --type headless failed:
>   VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'minikube' has terminated
>   unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1) VBoxManage: error:
>   Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap,
>   interface IMachine
>
> Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love
>   to hear from you:  
>   https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running next two commands solved the problem for me:

```
1- sudo apt autoremove 
2- sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

Note: when you run second command line "sudo /sbin/vboxconfig" you must see **Building VirtualBox kernal modules** message in logs, something like that

> vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
>
> vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
>
> vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.

Comment: any idea for win 10?similar problem with virtual box 6.0.8 and  minikube 1.1.0

Comment: @yuxh sorry, no idea about windows, i am using linux only. but you can search on how to run same commands from windows side, i guess this will help.

Comment: @yuxh, I posted some instructions on minikube for windows here on SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59203065/minikube-issue-on-windows-10-home-edition#answer-61785580