# Minikube issue on Windows 10 Home Edition

Tags: docker, minikube

I'm trying to install Minikube on Windows 10 Home. I don't have Hyper-V but i understand i can still use Minikube to as a remote Docker daemon as well as local Kubernetes cluster.

- Minikube
- Chocolatey

I appreciate the assistance please. When i tried starting minikube i get the following error:

[image]

So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows 10 Home Edition doesnt support Hyper V, you might want use VirtualBox instead.

Follow [Getting Start with Kubernetes in Windows 10 with Minikube and kubectl](https://medium.com/@vidurada/getting-start-with-kubernetes-in-windows-10-with-minikube-and-kubectl-32320d75d910)

In short:
 1)  install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

2) download, install chocolatey

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

3) install [kubernetes-cli](https://chocolatey.org/packages/kubernetes-cli)

```
choco install kubernetes-cli
```

4) start minikube with `--vm-driver=virtualbox` option

```
minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox
```

Answer (score 0):

These instructions are for setting up and installing Minikube and its dependencies for use on Windows Home editions that are using Docker Toolbox.

**Install Kubectl**

1. Create a new directory that you will move your `kubectl` binaries into. A good place would be `C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\bin` since these path variables will also be made available to the "Docker Quick Start" terminal.
2. Download the latest `kubectl` executable from the link on the Kubernetes doc page:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows

3. Move this downloaded `.exe` file into the bin directory you created.
4. Use Windows search to type “env” or “edit” then select “Edit the system environment variables”
5. In the System Properties dialog box, click “Environment Variables”.
6. In User Variables click on the “Path” Variable and then click “Edit”
7. Click “New” and then type `C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\bin`
8. Click "OK"
9. Restart your terminal and test by typing `kubectl` into it. You should get the basic commands and help menu printed back to your screen. If this doesn't work try restarting your machine.

**Install Minikube**

VirtualBox should already be installed from setting up Docker Toolbox, so we wont need to install this again.

To install Minikube we can use the standalone installer, which is available by clicking this link:

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/latest/download/minikube-installer.exe

After the installer finishes, restart your terminal and test your installation:

```
minikube status
```

Running `minikube start` will provision the VirtualBox machines and startup your Kubernetes services.